# CTE - Table lock

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014

I'm using SQL Server 2014.

Below is my SQL code:

```
;With MyCte as
(
    .../* This select takes 2 minutes */
) 
INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable(...)
SELECT ... FROM MyCte;
```

I know that INSERT operation locks the table.
My questions: Will the table (dbo.SomeTable) be locked while MyCte is being populated (using select that takes 2 minutes)? Or it'll be locked only while inserting?

Comment: An `INSERT` will lock **the row(s)** being inserted - ***NOT*** the table! (as long as you don't insert more than 5000 rows at once) And the CTE selecting the data will only incur a *shared* lock .....

Comment: You seem to imagine that the CTE gets "populated" then the insert happens. Unless the plan has a blocking operator rows flow straight from the select into the insert. CTEs do not exist as objects in their own right.

Comment: Ok, so instead of using even CTE...if I just use that select in the INSERT statement, will it be the same as this one?

Comment: In my experience, the shorter your insert/update/delete statement lives, the better off you are from a locking perspective.  If you don't have concurrency concerns, select into a temp table and then insert from that.  Alternatively, tune your query if possible.  (or both!)

Comment: @GreenBinary, it is easy to check. Check execution plan for the query with CTE and without. Most probably it will be exactly the same. @MartinSmith is right, if you want to guarantee that `SELECT` runs first with shared lock and only then update lock is placed on the rows/table, then use temporary table or table variable to hold results of `SELECT` and then `INSERT` into permanent table from the temporary.